# Strange disappearing fragment after screen rotate

Tags: android, android-fragments, rotation

Is it me or is Android really really weird? Sorry that's not my question..

I have a simple class I wrote to practice using fragments. instantiate two fragments of different colours and then allow a button push to switch between them. And it works perfectly --- as long as I don't rotate the phone. I can switch back and forth endlessly making the fragments switch back and forth. But if I rotate - say from land to port then I can only switch 3 times before both fragments disappear leaving me with an empty container.
   It seems so strange that after I rotate I get 3 more goes before it breaks - I can find no rhyme nor reason to it. --- to clarify I rotate once and its fine but after I press the swap button 3 times it simply goes to a blank screen which is I assume my empty container.

Here is my code:

```
package self.redway.dynamicfragment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    private FragmentOne frag1;
    private FragmentTwo frag2;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        frag1 = new FragmentOne();
        frag2 = new FragmentTwo();

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.layout1, frag1).commit();
    }

    public void callFrag2(View v)
    {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.layout1, frag2).commit();
    }

    public void callFrag1(View v)
    {   
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.layout1, frag1).commit();
    }
}
```

And the code for FragmentOne (actually exactly the same as FragmentTwo) :

```
package self.redway.dynamicfragment;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FragmentOne extends Fragment
{   
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_one, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

I have tried adding an empty constructor (made no difference). I think if I actually make two separate layouts - one for port and one for land that may help. I haven't tried that yet. But even if that works I would love to know why and what an earth is going on????

Here is the layout code for frag_one it is the same as frag_2 just a different color:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFF00"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:text="Hi I am fragment one giving my message. Please press the button to cycle to next Frag."
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Press Me"
        android:onClick="callFrag2"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

the main layout is literally just an empty layout which sole purpose is to hold the fragments dynamically.

Comment: What is the "swap button"? Also show your layout files.

Comment: I have editted to add layout of fragments. AS you can see it has a button defined in the layout that simply calls frag2 and the other one is the same but obviously calls frag1. So each fragment holds a button and if you press it it calls the method in main activity and that replaces it with the other fragment.

Comment: Have you tried monitoring logcat when doing this to see if anything significant is logged?

Comment: In the `onCreate()` method of your `Activity`, instead of using `add(R.id.layout1, frag1)` as your initial transaction try using `replace(R.id.layout1, frag1)` and see if that changes the behaviour you're seeing. I doubt it will but I'd be interested to know if it does.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I will get an error if I try and use replace on the first instance as there is no fragment to replace. I imagine the replace code will try and remove the original onto the stack and find that there is no fragment there and just complain. It may be an idea to use replace if (savedInstanceState != null) though. It is obviously some sort of restoration issue. I will give that a go and let you know on both counts. problem with logcat is I don't know what to filter for as it hasn't crashed or anthing it is just acting in a strange way, and without filter I will be lost!

Comment: Well we are both suprised!! lol it worked straight away without me having to even put it as a restore as a pose to initial action as I had thought I would. Program now works perfectly. Thanks :) I don't suppose you would know why? I find android a bit bizarre sometimes. Everything seems so much harder than normal Java programming!

Comment: I'm really not sure but it may have to do with the separate life-cycles of the `Activity` and `Fragment` classes. I'll do some further reading and if I find a reason I'll let you know. Glad it seems to have fixed the problem though.

Comment: Nope, I haven't got an answer even after reading through the `Fragment` source code. I can only guess that when you rotate, the existing `Fragment` is somehow retained and by calling `add(...)` in the new `Activity` instance you're overlaying the previous `Fragment` and things get out of sync. I knew `replace(...)` wouldn't fail as it can be used on an empty container (it checks to see if a `Fragment` exists or not). I didn't know for definite it would fix your problem. If I'm right about the previous `Fragment` being retained on rotation though, that might explain it.

Comment: Oh, as for Android being weird - no not really when you get used to it. The majority of Android programming is pretty much normal Java - you just need to get used to things like the life-cycles of the key application components such as `Activity`, `Fragment`, `BroadcastReceiver`, `Service` etc. Once you do that it's fairly intuitive. I'd never programmed with Java when I started with Android so learned both at the same time - I guess that helped as I had no preconceptions of how Android and Java should work together.

Comment: I'm certain you are right about the syncing issue. I think it is something to do with how replace puts the old fragment on the stack. The main thing is I have it working phew.. now onto learning intents :) Thanks again.